# Nifi: can't recognize groovy xmlSlurper structure

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

[enter image description here][1]I have nifi  1.3.0. Is it possible that  groovy version  which is implemented in nifi can't  recognize lambdas? Here is  my code,   how can I  change it to  make work inside nifi  processor?

1. is  it  possible that   processor  doesn;t  work  properly  because  i   don't  use  session.tranfer i mean  don't  produce any   flowfile?

> ```
> def static addDays(def date) {
>         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
>         Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
>         c.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
>         c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // number of days to add
>         String m = sdf.format(c.getTime());  // dt is now the new date
>         return m;
>     }
> def  flowFile=session.get()
> ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<>();
> if(flowFile!=null){   
>   value.add(flowFile.getAttribute('filename');
>   session.remove(flowFile);
>       }
>  File file = new File("C://Users//user//Desktop//try2//nifi-1.3.0//4//conf2.xml");
>         String content = "";
>         String material = "";
>         BufferedReader s;
>         BufferedWriter w;
>         RandomAccessFile ini = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rwd");
>         FileLock lock = ini.getChannel().lock();
>         DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
>         Document document, doc;
>         String date="",data="";
>         try {
>             String sCurrentLine;
>             s = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(ini.getChannel(), "UTF-8"));
>             while ((sCurrentLine = s.readLine()) != null) {
>                 content += sCurrentLine;
>             }
>             ini.seek(0);
>           def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(content)
>             for(int i=0;i<value.size();i++) {
>                 date = value.get(i).substring(0, 10);
>                 xml.rs.borderCross.details.findAll({ p ->
>                     p.runAs[0].text() == "false" && p.start[0].text() == date.toString()
>                 }).each({ p ->
>                     p.start[0].value = addDays( p.start[0].text())
>                     p.runAs[0].value = "true"
>                 })
>             }
>             def stringWriter = new StringWriter()
>             new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(stringWriter)).print(xml)
>             def newXml = stringWriter.toString()
>             TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
>             Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
>             InputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(newXml.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
>             DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory1 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
>             dBuilder = dbFactory1.newDocumentBuilder();
>             document = dBuilder.parse(stream1);
>             DOMSource source=new DOMSource(document);
>             ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>             StreamResult result1 = new StreamResult(bos);
>             try {
>                 transformer.transform(source, result1);
>             } catch (TransformerException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>             byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();
>             data = bos.toString();
>             if (!data.isEmpty()) {
>                  ini.setLength(0);
>                 w = new BufferedWriter(Channels.newWriter(ini.getChannel(), "UTF-8"));
>                 w.write(data);
>                 lock.release();
>                 w.close();
>             }
>             else{
>                 ini.setLength(0);
>                 w = new BufferedWriter(Channels.newWriter(ini.getChannel(), "UTF-8"));
>                 w.write(content);
>                 lock.release();
>                 w.close();
>
>             }
>         }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
>             TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(50000);
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (SAXException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {
>       TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(50000);
>             lock.release(); ;
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } finally {
>             //lock.release();
>             ini.close();
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't Java lambdas, they are Groovy closures. At first glance that looks correct, what error(s) are you getting? You may need to put the closures in parentheses before chaining them:

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(content)
            for(int i=0;i<value.size();i++) {
                date = value.get(i).substring(0, 10);
                xml.rs.borderCross.details.findAll({ p ->
                    p.runAs[0].text() == "false" && p.start[0].text() == date.toString()
                }).each({ p ->
                    p.start[0].value = addDays( p.start[0].text())
                    p.runAs[0].value = "true"
                })
            }
```

Comment: MulipleCompilationErrorsException:startup failed unexpected   token

Comment: and   when i  see  the  line number  error shows  me  i have  simple  String  s=" "  on this   line  can't  find  out  why  this error is  trown

Comment: when i  run this  on intelij  idea  code  works   perfectly  but inside nifi  processor  code it  throws exceptions

Comment: The line you refer to is not in your script above, can you please share the entire script? It will be hard to help you if you are not sharing the line(s) that are actually causing the error.

Comment: this   line    is   mentioned in   error  String date="",data="";

Comment: That’s not how multiple assignments are done in Groovy, check this link for more details: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-multiple-assignments.html?m=1

Comment: If  i  write  def  String a=" "  and  then  def String  b=" "  on  the  second  line  it   would    be  compatible  with  groovy ?  i  guess  assert  34==value  does't works   properly

Comment: The asserts in that post are to show that the assignments work. The first line is the example, you want “def (date,data) = [‘’,’’]”

Comment: By  the   way  do   you  see any  obvious  reason  why  this  code can't  work?  now it  doesn't  even  throws exception   but  when  i  run  it  on  intelij idea   it  works

Comment: how  to  prevent adding  tabs  when  the  code is    complited?